# Make a div scollable on overflow-y but at the same time overflow-x should be completely visible

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, overflow, react-typescript

Let me start by providing the [stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-79pncq?file=index.tsx) for my problem in case what I have described is confusing.
I'm Working on a react typescript project and building the UI as per wireframes provided. I have vertical container with a fixed width, that contains cards displayed one below the other. When we hover over one of the cards the card width should expand like so:

[image]

The code for this part is:
**index.ts**

```js
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      payload: [
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'AB' },
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'CD' },
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'EF' },
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'GH' },
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'IJ' },
        { text: 'sdsdgfdghgf', heading: 'Heading', intitials: 'KL' },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="container-light">
          {this.state.payload.map((item: any) => (
            <div className="card"></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**styles.css**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-light {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100px;
}

.card {
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
  margin: 0px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.card:hover {
  width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #1473e6;
}
```

Then, if we decrease the height of the browser window, I need my outer container to be scollable while maintaining the hover behaviour. But once I add `overflow-y: auto` to the scrollable container, it hides my horizontally overflowing data too. Looks like this:

[image]

To achieve scrolling I added `overflow-y: auto;` and `height: 300px;` to `.container-light` i.e. my scrollable div.

I have a kind of a half formed hacky solution with CSS, where I'm making the div `position: fixed;` on hover and modifying its sibling's margin, Like so:

```css
.card:hover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px; /* have to calculate this dynamically somehow */
}
.card:hover + .card {
  margin-top: 66px; 
}
```

I'm stuck here. If I figure out my hack then I guess I can keep that for the time being. But if I'm missing something super obvious or if anyone has a different solution I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.container {
  min-width:320px
}
```

Comment: I need the width of those containers to be fixed. Only the card width must expand

Comment: the problem here would be the scrollbar. Where exactly do you need the scrollbar to appear? if you do as I suggested , the scrollbar will be 320px from the left border. If you want it to appear 100px from the left border, making the hovered card to appear on top of it, you can use :
```.container-light, container{
   overflow-x : visible
}```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Scrollbar should be on the `.container-light` div which is 100px wide. `.container` div is just a wrapper.